# Activity life cycle

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, Подкуйте в чем трабл... В Main_Activity есть 3 ImageButton и они ведут к вызову 3 разных Activity. Но проблема в том, что вызываются новые окна самопроизвольно. 
Вот пару логов где почему то salati_list вместо lapsha_list

`05-22 19:40:07.429 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onCreate()
05-22 19:40:07.430 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onStart()
05-22 19:40:07.430 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onResume()
05-22 19:40:12.389 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onPause()
05-22 19:40:12.738 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onCreate()
05-22 19:40:12.754 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onStart()
05-22 19:40:12.754 17915-17915/? D/States: salati_list: onStart()
05-22 19:40:12.754 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onResume()
05-22 19:40:12.754 17915-17915/? D/States: salati_list: onResume()
05-22 19:40:13.176 17915-17915/? D/States: MainActivity: onStop ()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageButton imageButton_lapsha;
ImageButton imageButton_supi;
ImageButton imageButton_salati;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageButton_lapsha= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton_lapsha.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton_supi= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imageButton_supi.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton_salati= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imageButton_salati.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.imageButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, lapsha_list.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        case R.id.imageButton2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, supi_list.class);
            startActivity(intent2);

        case R.id.imageButton3:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, salati_list.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            // TODO Call second activity
    }
}
```

}

Сброшу еще манифест, на всякий случай, вот не знаю в чем проблема. Спасибо.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".lapsha_list">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".supi_list">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".salati_list">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Я почти на android ничего не писал и могу ошибатся, но android.intent.action.MAIN  означает главную активити, т.е точку входа в приложение. При старте она создается первым делом. Возможно окна у вас самопроизвольно появляются из-за этого. [android.intent.action.MAIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема было в онклин, нужно было дописать брейк.

Answer (score 3):

проблема было в онклин, нужно было дописать брейк

```
case R.id.imageButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, lapsha_list.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            **break;**
```